# Restricting who can send to an email address

Tags: postfix, procmail

I'd like to do so that only certain From: addresses can send to an email address (mailing list) on an Ubuntu system running Postfix.

Understanding the Postfix the manuals are requires a lot of knowledge, so I'm hoping to get a complete recipe I can use. Currently this is what I have:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations
smtpd_restriction_classes = insiders_only
insiders_only = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, reject

/etc/postfix/protected_destinations:
protected.list@example.com insiders_only

/etc/postfix/insiders:
allowed.user@example.com OK
another.allowed.user@example.com OK
```

This gives:

```
fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit
```

I am open to any suggestions. It doesn't have to be Postfix. It can be procmail or any other standard solution.

Note: the recipient is a mailing list, and thus does not have a user account on the system account. So any solution must work without an account.

#### Current mailing list implementation

```
/etc/postfix/virtual:
protected.list@example.com user1@example.com, user2.example.com, ...
```

Comment: How is the mailing list implemented? Using dedicated mailing list software, or just a mail server alias that expands to a list of recipients?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: See recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read and understand the error message?  You should have something like

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations,
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_unauth_destination
```

... which is your rule in front of the output from `postconf -d` on a random Debian box here.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done that in postfix, so I don't know the syntax for everything, but, when you use hashed database (and you have `hash:` in front of the filenames), you need to actually hash the files to create the databases, from the postfix documentation:

> The database name as used in "hash:table" is the database file name without the ".db" suffix.

Did you run `postmap` on the files to create those databases (sorry, but I don't remember how the `postmap` invocations should look, but I think it's just `postmap <file>` (when you want to to create `<file>.db`)).

Answer (score -5):

Restricting send email address
By default, users with Gmail accounts at your domain can send mail to and receive mail from any other email address. However, in some cases, you may want to restrict the email addresses your users can exchange mail with. For example, a school might want to allow its students to exchange mail with the faculty and other students, but not with people outside of the school.

Use the Restrict delivery setting to allow the sending or receiving of email messages only from addresses or domains that you specify. When you add a Restrict delivery setting, users cannot communicate with anyone, except those authorized.

Comment: I see that you're actually quoting from [Google's official support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542). Next time, provide the actual reference, and use `> block quote` to quote it properly. Plagiarizing is unacceptable here.